# How to add a name server to Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, root, dns, ping

I can ping to 8.8.8.8. I want to use automatic DNS or help me make it 8.8.8.8. I can't enter GUI, system crashed. I connected via wifi using root option in recovery. Crashed during upgrade to Ubuntu 17. `resolv.conf/head` shows nothing. Because I can't resolve name, I can't do an upgrade or install commands. I searched other answers, but I couldn't find a proper one.

**Issue**
[image]

Want to make dhclient push nameserver information to resolvconf.[image: man page]

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223/10017

Comment: @Rinzwind i went through it before and its confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing r/w permission in root as its not there when opened in recovery mode. Once i did it i was able to get connected.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

found out that you can change the nameservers that dnsmasq uses by adding the following lines to /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
I didn't have a /etc/dnsmasq.conf file though, since it's installed by the dnsmasq package, but Ubuntu only comes with dnsmasq-base. I ran sudo apt-get install dnsmasq, then edited /etc/dnsmasq.conf, then sudo service dnsmasq restart and sudo service network-manager restart.

I ran sudo tail -n 200 /var/log/syslog to check my syslog and verify that dnsmasq was using the nameservers I specified:

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Append your ISP name server or free fast dns nameservers IP address as follows:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 202.51.5.52
```

Save and close the file. Test your dns configuration by typing the following commands:

```
$ host yahoo.com
$ nslookup google.com
$ ping nixcraft.in
```

Comment: And we ignore the "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN" notice in the file why exactly? `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` is the place to do this.

Comment: Rohith: No file resolv.conf. In ubuntu 16.10. And @Rinzwind i cant save gives out read only. I just want to make dhclient to push nameserver information to resolvconf.

Comment: That's another option yes. For dhclient use `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases` It will automatically make/fill /etc/resolv.conf` (oh it can also be `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases` where eth0 needs to be changed to your nic name)

Comment: @Rinzwind:Can you give me exact command?